# Rails Asset Pipeline: process a single Javascript file to known name/location

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I have a Javascript file that needs to appear at a fixed location on my server. What's the best way to allow this file to participate in the asset pipeline (so I can get all the benefits from compression and 6to5), yet always have the file end up in a known location, free of the digest signature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is an [extremely divisive issue](https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/issues/49) for the Sprockets team. Two years later it's still unresolved.

For now the best solution seems to be the [non-stupid-digest-assets](https://github.com/alexspeller/non-stupid-digest-assets) gem.